# Google Heatmap - no pointer on map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

i'm using google heat map and i'm trying to load over 1000 pointer on the map, but i'm not sure it's working.

This is my code:

```
        var map, pointarray, heatmap;

        var gradient = [
            'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)',
            'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)',
            'rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)',
            'rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)',
            'rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)',
            'rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)',
            'rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)',
            'rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
        ]

 var taxiData = [
new google.maps.LatLng(43.3128954, 10.5320177),
new google.maps.LatLng(43.4121300, 10.4157520),
....
new google.maps.LatLng(43.3116784, 10.5298907),
new google.maps.LatLng(43.3416850, 10.5290120) 
]

        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 13,
                dissipating: false,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.3128954, 10.5320177),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

            pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(taxiData);

            heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                data: pointArray
            });

            heatmap.setMap(map);
            heatmap.set('gradient', heatmap.get('gradient') ? null : gradient);
        }

        function toggleHeatmap() {
            heatmap.setMap(heatmap.getMap() ? null : map);
        }

        function changeGradient() {
            var gradient = [
                'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)',
                'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)',
                'rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)',
                'rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)',
                'rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
            ]
            heatmap.set('gradient', heatmap.get('gradient') ? null : gradient);
        }

        function changeRadius() {
            heatmap.set('radius', heatmap.get('radius') ? null : 20);
        }

        function changeOpacity() {
            heatmap.set('opacity', heatmap.get('opacity') ? null : 0.2);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I've created a demo with the complete code at this link: http://jsfiddle.net/8b85R/

[fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8b85R/1/embedded/result/) (button clicks work)

I didn't understand why i've a lot blue areas, but only 2 pointer! i was expecting something more similar to the Google Demo ( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap ) where you can find all the 500 pointers.

I need your help!
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by a "pointer"?  A heatmap isn't going to show individual points.  Your jsfiddle has errors when you click on the buttons.  [fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8b85R/1/embedded/result/) (that zooms to show all the points)

Comment: For "pointer" i mean the exact position for the google.maps.LatLng coordinates on map

Answer (score 1):

Something more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6JSe7/1/ ?

All I did was dial down (or up number wise) the opacity, the points were there at increasing zoom levels but they were barely visible (by which I mean pretty well undetectable), and added the dissipating option:

```
heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: pointArray,
            dissipating: true,
            radius: 35

        });

        heatmap.setMap(map);
        heatmap.set('gradient', heatmap.get('gradient') ? null : gradient);
        heatmap.set('opacity', '0.9');
```

Comment: it looks better now, but it's not like i want. I'm trying to explain better..
If you look the demo on Google (you can find the link on the topic), if you zoom the map you can see exactly where google.maps.LatLng coordinates are, but this not happen on my demo.

Any ideas?